# loop through a for statement using an if/else with nunjucks and json

Tags: json, for-loop, if-statement, nunjucks, eleventy

I'm trying to loop through a nested json file with nunjucks, give each object type a specific layout and sort all based on date.

So in my case I have two collections events and videos. Both collections will have an array of events and videos.

My file is named /content.json and structured as followed:

```
{
    media: {
        events: [
            {
            content_id: "1",
            content_type: "event",
            date: "01-11-2019",
            etc: "etc"
            },
            {
            content_id: "2",
            content_type: "event",
            date: "01-08-2019",
            etc: "etc"
            }
        ],
        videos: [
            {
            content_id: "3",
            content_type: "video",
            date: "01-12-2019",
            etc: "etc"
            },
            {
            content_id: "4",
            content_type: "video",
            date: "01-09-2019",
            etc: "etc"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried to get the different object assigned with an if/else statement and then use a for loop to cycle through the array, but that has failed, see below:

```
{% for item in content.media %}
    {% if item == events %}
        {% for item in content.media.events %}
                {% include "components/event.njk" %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% elif item ==  video %}
        {% for item in content.media.videos %}
                {% include "components/video.njk" %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I never got to try and sort all the content by date, but I have found:

```
{% for item in items|sort(attribute='date')%}
```

Can anyone guide me in right direction?

Thanks in advance.

AENM

Comment: `{% for event in content.media.events %}...{% endfor %} {% for video in content.media.videos %}...{% endfor %}`?

Comment: Thnx Aikon, I did have this solution and it works. But I in the I want to sort all content by date. And knowing nunjucks provides a sorting option, all the content should be in one for statement. Maybe you say, this isn't possible, you need some javascript to do the sorting. Or maybe you have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

This code outputs separated feeds by type of elements (event or video).

```
{% for event in content.media.events | sort(attribute = 'date') %}
    {% include "components/event.njk" %}
{% endfor %}

{% for video in content.media.videos | sort(attribute = 'date') %}
    {% include "components/video.njk" %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you need to output a mixed feed, you should join arrays to one and run trought it (fortunately each elements already have the type):

```
{% for item in [].concat(content.media.events, content.media.videos) | sort(attribute = 'date') %}
    {% include "components/" + item.content_type + ".njk" %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Aikon, I tried the first and it worked, but I had to change into sort('date'). The second returned an error, saying : `TemplateContentRenderError` was thrown
> (./site/index.njk)
  Error: template not found: components/undefined.njk. I tested it and I has to do with the concat function. It is not working properly? :-(

Comment: I fixed the "error": your data doesn't content `type`-field but `content_type`.

Comment: See my answer above. It was the content.media, which had to be media.content. Now it all works fine!!

Comment: Yes, correct. But I dont want to go into deep as this is more a wireframe type of build. But I probably have to do something with moment.js and https://github.com/techmsi/nunjucks-date. Thanks for the tips and your help again.

Answer (score 0):

Aikon,

I got it now!! 
It was another typo, you switched the media and events. (did you try to keep me sharp?! :-)) 
But that's why the concat didn't work!! 
So this is the final working result:

```
{% for item in [].concat(media.content.events, media.content.videos) | sort(attribute = 'date') %}
     {% include "components/" + item.type + ".njk" %}
{% endfor %}
```

Only the date is not in the correct order, but I think that has to with my grid setup.

Thanks for helping me out......

Comment: I think that you have date issue because nunjucks compares `events.date` as strings, not date. So you should create own custom filter instead standard `sort`.